# How can I give write permission to a specified user in Firebase?

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication, firebase-security

I have a mobile application which reads the data from the firebase server without firebase login/authentication (posts and news) and I want to create an admin webpage where I can log in and add, or modify news, so I need a write permission there. My rules are currently:

```
{
  "rules": {
    ".read": true,
    ".write": "auth !== null && ?????
  }
}
```

Can I write something like `"user.emailAddress == 'mail@example.com'"`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You might want to start by reading the documentation about [securing user data](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/security/user-security).  There is a lot to know here.

One possibility is using the known user's uid to restrict access.  The `auth.uid` variable contains the uid.

```
".write": "auth.uid == 'the-known-uid'"
```

Also you can use [`auth.token`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/security/database/#authtoken) to access some other things about the user, including email address (which may not be present):

```
".write": "auth.token.email == 'the@email.address'"
```

You can also use custom authentication tokens, which also is [covered in the documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/security/user-security#section-custom).

Answer (score 5):

You can create a users table on database like

```
{
  "users":{
     "your UID":{
        "isAdmin": true
      }
   }
}
```

Then edit rules :

```
{
  "rules": {
    ".read": true,
    ".write": "auth.uid != null && root.child("users").child(auth.uid).isAdmin === true"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Create database:

```
   {
      "users":{
         "your UID":{
            "isAdmin": true
          }
       }
    }
```

Set rules:

Wrong:

```
    {
      "rules": {
        ".read": true,
        ".write": "auth.uid != null && root.child("users").child(auth.uid).isAdmin === true"
      }
    }
```

Right:

```
    {
      "rules": {
        ".read": true,
        ".write": "auth.uid != null && root.child('users').child(auth.uid).child('isAdmin').val() === true"
      }
    }
```